# What should the route be in Web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this method in Web API

```
public class ProjectsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetProjects(string searchKeyword, int startRow, int endRow)
        {
            DataSet dsResult = ProjectsDB.GetProjects(searchKeyword, startRow, endRow);

            if (dsResult == null)
            {
                dsResult = new DataSet();
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsResult, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
```

and the route configs are

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

and

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The calling function is:

```
private async Task<List<Project>> GetProjects(ResultFilters model)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
            string response = null;
            List<Project> lstProjects = new List<Project>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalConstants.WebAPIURL + "/api/Projects/GetProjects");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress, model).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    lstProjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(response);
                }                 
            }

            return lstProjects;
        }
```

The ResultFilters object has the parameter values that are required for the API method.

The above code returns no data and I suspect either the API is not hit or it could be a routing issue. I also had no luck in getting to debug the Web API.

1. What am I doing wrong here.
2. If the route configs are to be changed, then there would be multiple methods for every controller, each may have different params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a GET method and you issued a POST against it.

I suspect you would like it to be a POST so change the HTTP verb on your API method.

Next, check your model and make sure it matches what the API method needs.

the model should look like this :

```
public class ResultFilters {
   public string searchKeyword { get; set; }
   public int startRow { get; set; }
   public int endRow { get; set; }
}
```

your API method then can look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string FilterProjects([FromBody] ResultFilters filters)
        {
            DataSet dsResult = ProjectsDB.GetProjects(filters.searchKeyword, filters.startRow, filters.endRow);

            if (dsResult == null)
            {
                dsResult = new DataSet();
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsResult, Formatting.Indented);
        }
```

Of course you need to look at your method names, no point having a *GetProjects* method which is a *POST*. I actually renamed it in my answer because I can't stand this *Get which is a POST* fallacy.

If you want to change it to a get then you can use a FromURI attribute and of course change your calling code accordingly.

Comment: But the method is actually to 'get' projects. Any other name would not be justified...:(

Comment: well, you can look at it as filtering projects as well. up to you really. if it's a GET then you can't issue a POST against it, so you need to change something. you have 2 options in my answer, either make it a post and use the code I showed, or change everything to a get and then modify your calling code accordingly